# Prove that set is not a compact

Tags: compactness, bounded-variation

I need to prove that in metric space $\Bbb{R}^2$ the set $$1\lt x^2+y^2 \le 4 $$is not compact.

I know theorem, that
$$A\subset\Bbb{R}^n \; is \;a \; compact \iff A \; is \; bounded \; and \;closed.$$
But this doesn't work for me, because I need to prove it by definition of compact.

Comment: A set is compact if every open cover admits a finite subcover. Can you show this to be true?

Comment: You can show this is not closed, take a sequence convegence to an element with $x^2+y^2=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The family $B_n=\{(x,y) | 1+\frac{1}{n} <x^2+y^2 \leq 4\}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.